# Spring-boot UTF-8 resources

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot (I'm following [this tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)), the current code is [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/tree/master/complete).

My application is configured via `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, so I don't have `web.xml`, or other configuration files.
The application has a default handler for `/**`, files from `projectRoot/src/main/webapp/` are served, but unfortunately with `Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1`. I'd like to serve (`html` files) with `UTF-8` charset.

The static files are served by spring too, as far as I know: after launching the application, the following line apprears in the log: `Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]` (github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L182, sorry, I cannot post more than 2 links)

Putting `<meta charset="utf-8" />` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8" />` into the served `html` file has no effect.

How can I serve `*.html` files with `UTF-8` charset?

The debug log is the following:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v0.5.0.M6)

2013-11-24 00:48:41.327  INFO 15786 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on ubuntu with PID 15786 (/home/lennon/bme/szoftarch/szoftarch-2013-osz/build/libs/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar started by lennon)
2013-11-24 00:48:41.331 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class hello.Application
2013-11-24 00:48:41.380  INFO 15786 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7455ffcd: startup date [Sun Nov 24 00:48:41 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-11-24 00:48:41.385 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7455ffcd: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@54cb8484: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,application]; root of factory hierarchy
2013-11-24 00:48:42.179 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Using MessageSource [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource: basenames=[messages]]
2013-11-24 00:48:42.182 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@5d36368]
2013-11-24 00:48:42.518 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: /home/lennon/bme/szoftarch/szoftarch-2013-osz/build/libs/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
2013-11-24 00:48:42.518 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: /home/lennon/bme/szoftarch/szoftarch-2013-osz/build/libs/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
2013-11-24 00:48:42.518 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Document root: /home/lennon/bme/szoftarch/szoftarch-2013-osz/src/main/webapp
2013-11-24 00:48:42.904  INFO 15786 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2013-11-24 00:48:42.905  INFO 15786 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2013-11-24 00:48:43.006  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2013-11-24 00:48:43.007  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1630 ms
2013-11-24 00:48:43.259  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2013-11-24 00:48:43.260  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2013-11-24 00:48:43.428  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-11-24 00:48:43.717  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/greeting],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public hello.Greeting hello.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String)
2013-11-24 00:48:43.725  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.c.a.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter      : Adding welcome page: jndi:/localhost/index.html
2013-11-24 00:48:43.732  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Root mapping to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]
2013-11-24 00:48:43.811  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-11-24 00:48:43.812  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-11-24 00:48:44.489  INFO 15786 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 1229 ms
2013-11-24 00:48:44.641 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@10d6fc05]
2013-11-24 00:48:44.644 DEBUG 15786 --- [           main] nitializer$AutoConfigurationReportLogger : 


=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.MessageSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory] (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration#dispatcherServlet
      - no DispatcherServlet found (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DefaultDispatcherServletCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration#serverProperties
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#hiddenHttpMethodFilter
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   RabbitAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate,com.rabbitmq.client.Channel (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect,org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice (OnClassCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository (OnClassCondition)

   MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: com.mongodb.Mongo,org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)

   JmsTemplateAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate,javax.jms.ConnectionFactory (OnClassCondition)

   DeviceResolverAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor,org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement,javax.persistence.EntityManager,org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager (OnClassCondition)

   ReactorAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: reactor.spring.context.config.EnableReactor (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server,org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader (OnClassCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#beanNameViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.View; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#viewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.View; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler (OnClassCondition)

2013-11-24 00:48:44.650  INFO 15786 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 4.125 seconds
```

Comment: Show us the default handler configuration.

Comment: There are no configuration files, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` handles everything.

Comment: No I don't think so. Things directly in `src/main/webapp` are public resources and are handled by Tomcat's `DefaultServlet` unless specified otherwise. You will have to check if `EnableAutoConfiguration` specifies its own resource handler or configure one yourself.

Comment: I've updated the question. I believe the files are served by Spring.

Comment: Can you please post your full log in trace or debug mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Tomcat `DefaultServlet` is enabled by default, but only as a fallback, and I think static resources in the main `ServletContext` root will be handled by Spring's `DispatcherServlet` (with a vanilla Boot app anyway). In the embedded case (like in the guide you quoted) you can add mime mappings explicitly in an initializer callback, e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleWebStaticApplication implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("html", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        factory.setMimeMappings(mappings );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SampleWebStaticApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

If you need more control you can probably do something at the resource handler level.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/0.5.0.M6/api/org/springframework/boot/context/initializer/FileEncodingApplicationContextInitializer.html) leads me to believe that you should be able to influence the character encoding by setting the file.encoding system variable and/or the LANG or LC_ALL environment variables.

I'm assume that character encoding on the Content-Type will then follow the file.encoding setting.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, starting the application with `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 java -jar build/libs/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"` has no effect, the file is still served with ISO-8859-1.

Comment: OS concepts like LANG should not be applied to the application level, as encodings is a per-case issue and not all encoding within an application need to be the same. Additionally, LANG is not cross-OS, while Java/Spring is.